Passport Control at Frankfurt airport
As a passport holder of a Schengen country with a Canadian partner, can we both queue for the Schengen line at the passport control at the airport in Frankfurt am Main?

Technically yes but in practice it varies with the mood of the immigration officer. In my experience the German ones tend to be more on the reasonable side but can be stickler for rules and it may depend on the exact definition of "partner".

Not directly a concern for you but others might be interested to know that the rules do not depend on your being a citizen of a Schengen country. They also apply equally to non-Schengen EU countries. For Switzerland, I cannot recall but it should have already been the case when the first package of bilateral agreements came into effect (including freedom of movement for persons) and not the second package (which included Schengen membership).

I'm not sure how things are set up at FRA, but at least at CDG, U.S. and Canadian passport holders can use the e-gates just like EU passport holders. I've done it multiple times, both entering and exiting Schengen. I was using a U.S. passport, but Canadians were also eligible.

If your partner is a "family member" under EU regulations (parents, minor children, spouses, or [in some cases] civil partners) then under the Schengen Borders Code they can use the "EU, EEA, CH" lane when they are travelling with you or travelling to join you. Otherwise, they are meant to use the "all passports" lane.
In practice, the agent is unlikely to take issue with a person presenting themselves at the EU/EEA/CH counter together with an EU citizen they're travelling with.

In practice, if you're traveling together they'd prefer if you present to them together, side by side. EU or all passports line is up to you to decide, but whichever you pick, you should probably both use it. However, because you won't be asked questions and your partner will (return flight, itinerary etc), you should probably use the all passports line so that you don't cause delays on the EU line.
